# Three20 Presenting ViewController on top of Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, three20

I am using Three20 framework and trying to presentViewController on top of navigationController. I am not sure how its been done with Three20 framework, any guru's out there who have touched this framework might help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "limited support" for iPad & multiple view controllers on the same screen. I would avoid using the `TTNavigator` and the view controllers url mapping. you can just push and present your `TTViewController` classes using the standard `self.navigationController` work flow

PS, by "limited support" I mean horrible, buggy and useless support.

Comment: I had to take self.navigationController approach as I didn't see anything else as a good choice.